# I cannot get a taken picture just pictures from screenshot

Tags: java, android

I can't get the normal taken picture by my phone in java. Everything is working while I choose picture from the gallery which is screenshot but when It's normal taken picture it's not returning anything. I will give you some parts of the code where u can see how I'm getting picture.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);


        if (reqCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            final String path = getPath(getActivity(), imageUri);
            if (path != null) {

                try {
                    File f1 = new File(path);

                    final AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(true, 80, 443);
                    client.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
                    final RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                    params.put("id", id);
                    params.put("token", token);
                    params.put("avatar", f1);
```

And also this

```
add_avatar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //   filePickUtils.requestImageGallery(STORAGE_PERMISSION_IMAGE, true, true);
                if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // Should we show an explanation?
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        // Explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
                    }

                    requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            1);

                    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
                    // app-defined int constant that should be quite unique

                    return;
                }

                if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // Should we show an explanation?
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        // Explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
                    }

                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            1);

                    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
                    // app-defined int constant that should be quite unique

                    return;
                }

                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                photoPickerIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                photoPickerIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PICK_IMAGE);

            }
        });
```

What would you suggest?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you only need to read the image, and upload the data to your backend server, I'd suggest if you use `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` instead of `Intent.ACTION_PICK`.

**Why**

Your problem might related to what `Intent.ACTION_PICK` needs to have. The documentation stated:

> Input: getData() is URI containing a directory of data (vnd.android.cursor.dir/*) from which to pick an item.

So it means, if you want to use `Intent.ACTION_PICK`, you need to provide the directory of the data.

Meanwhile if you use `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, you can just set the MIME type of the file that you want to search (just as what you are doing now), and use `Context.startActivity(intent)`.

Additional note from the documentation that you might want to read:

> Input: `getType()` is the desired MIME type to retrieve. Note that no URI is supplied in the intent, as there are no constraints on where the returned data originally comes from. You may also include the `CATEGORY_OPENABLE` if you can only accept data that can be opened as a stream. You may use `EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY` to limit content selection to local data. You may use `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` to allow the user to select multiple items.
>
> Output: The URI of the item that was picked. This must be a `content:` URI so that any receiver can access it.

Add a comment here, if you need further information.

**Sample Code:**

In your activity

```
private searchImageFile() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.GET_CONTENT);

    // Filter to only show results that can be "opened"
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    // Filter to show only images, using the image MIME data type.
    // it would be "*/*".
    intent.setType("image/*");

    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {

    if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        final Uri imageUri = resultData.getData();
        //Do something with your Uri. 
    }
}
```